# How to open source file in IDE on a certain line through command line

Tags: delphi, ide, command-line-arguments, delphi-2007, assert

I'm just wondering if there is some IDE command line parameter which would open a source file on a specified line (in the current view) ?

I know this is probably too much to publish as a command line parameter, but it would be great for my Assert logging system; I would just create a link (label or something) and through this link open the file on the line where the assertion has happened.

---

The only thing I found is the registry entry (valid for Delphi 2007)

Key:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\BDS\5.0\Closed Files\`

Value:

`TSourceModule,'<FilePath>',0,<PositionX>,<PositionY>,<CursorX>,<CursorY>,0,0,,`

Where:

`<FilePath> - the full file path`
`<PositionX> - first visible char in horizontal scope`
`<PositionY> - first visible char in vertical scope`
`<CursorX> - cursor position in horizontal scope`
`<CursorY> - cursor position in vertical scope`

The rest of this key value I don't know but it might be enough to create this key and open the file.

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be the IDE. It would presumably be easy to achieve in a text editor.

Comment: @David, IDE would be the best (even if the project won't be opened I still be able to CTRL + Click through the syntax, with the proper environment configuration of course).

Comment: It must be cached somewhere. IDE remembers the line where I've ended my work for each file. Probably in registry for the MRU files, so I should be able to override it somehow. But some magical cmd parameter would be the best.

Comment: That information is stored in the project .dsk file. I guess you could create a fake project and a fake .dsk file and trick the IDE into opening at the desired place.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm doing this in Delphi 2007 and there are no .dsk files (yet?). But still I think it must be somewhere else because the IDE remembers also the single file in separate directory (where no .dpr is stored).

Comment: D2007 has .dsk files. D6 had them.

Comment: @David, so in that case I have a wrong configuration or something. I can't find any .dsk file in my project folders.

Comment: Well, I've never used D2007 (lucky for me) but it seems unlikely that the .dsk files would have been removed and then added back. But you never know!

Comment: @David, and have the future or past Delphi releases the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\BDS\X.X\Closed Files\` values like I described in my Q edit?

Comment: Do you mean always go to a certain line (like the last line you were working on) when you open the project? If so, David's on the right path. Go to Tools|Options|Environment Options (may be slightly different in D2007) and check 'AutoSave Options|Project Desktop'. This will save all open tabs (and the source location in each source file) when you save the project, and restore it the next time you open it.

Comment: @David: no they have not been removed and re-added, but you do have to check the "Project desktop" option on Tools | Options | Environment options | Autosave options, or no dsk files will be saved.

Comment: @Marjan and Ken, good to know. For this purpose .dsk files will be fine. I'll setup this option and analyze the .dsk file. Then I'll create my fictive one and open the project with certain .pas file on a specified line.

Comment: @David, so post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following discussion in the comments to the question, it appears that you would be satisfied with writing a small utility to generate a fake .dsk file (desktop file) and possibly a matching fake .dproj file (project file). The .dsk file would contain just enough information to trick the IDE into opening the required file and moving to the desired location within that file.

Comment: This is exactly what's accomplished by checking the "AutoSave Options|Project Desktop" that Marjan and I mentioned in the comments above. It creates the .dsk file to save the desktop settings (that's what a .dsk file is, after all.) :)

Comment: @Ken, certainly yes, but to open the source file on specific line I need to create either a fake .dsk file or overwrite the existing one as David said. I don't want to open the source where I finished my work, I want to open it on a certain line.